# Django: Redirect between two apps from views.py

Tags: django

There are two apps: `app_user` and `app_test`.
`app_user` contains a `login.html` (with custom login forms). The login is realized using a POST request in JS, which calls a function `api_login` in `app_user.views.py`.

This is my very simple login function (for testing):

```
def api_login(request):
    # Get post data
    post = json.loads(request.body)
    # Get username and password
    username = post.get('username', None)
    password = post.get('password', None)
    # Returned data object
    data = {
        "success": False,
        "username": username,
    }
    # Username and password
    if username == "" or password == "":
        data['success'] = False
        return JsonResponse(data)
    # Check if input is correct
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        data['success'] = True
        login(request, user)
        # return JsonResponse(data) <-- No data response, there should be a redirect 
        return redirect('app_test:test-home')
    else:
        data['success'] = False
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

This works well but I want to make a redirect from `http://localhost:8000/login/` (included by `app_user`) to `http://localhost:8000/test/` (included by `app_test`) when the login was **successful**.

My main url pattern (`urls.py`).

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('test/', include('app_test.urls'), name='app_test'),
    path('login/', include('app_user.urls'), name='app_login'),
]
```

Url pattern from `app_user`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.view_login, name='user-login'),
    path('api/login', views.api_login, name='user-api-login'),
]
```

Url pattern from `app_test`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.view_test, name='test-home'),
]
```

The JS setup:

```
function login() {
    let url = 'api/login';
    let data = {
        username: inputUsername.getValue(),
        password: inputPassword.getValue()
    };
    let onSuccess = function (data) {
        console.log('>> Success!');
        console.log(data);
    }
    let onServerError = function () {
        console.log('>> onServerError!');
        console.log(data);
    }
    let onError = function () {
        console.log('>> onError!');
        console.log(data);
    }
    request('POST', url, data, onSuccess, onServerError, onError);
}
```

```
function request(method, url, data, onSuccess, onServerError, onError) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(method, url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            // Success!
            console.log('Status: ' + request.status);
            onSuccess(request.response);
        } else {
            console.log('Status: ' + request.status);
            // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
            onServerError(request.response);
        }
    };

    request.onerror = function () {
        console.log('Status: ' + request.status);
        // There was a connection error of some sort
        onError(request.response);
    };
    if (method === 'GET') {
        console.log('>> GET');
        request.send();
    } else {
        console.log('>> POST');
        request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}
```

The **redirect** in `api_login` does not work using:
`redirect('test-home')` or `redirect('app_test:test-home')` (for this I added `app_name = 'app_test'` in `app_test.py`. So how can I make a redirect in `api_login` between two apps?

Comment: add the related js script also

Comment: I added the JS setup. The function ````getCookie('csrftoken')```` returns the csrf token. Without redirect it works correctly. So the returned data object contains success = true when the login was successful and false when the login failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you get for the valid login will be the html page for the url 'app_test:test-home'. You can check that in the browser developer tools. Need to get the JsonResponse for the request even for a valid login. Add the redirect url in the response and redirect using js instead.

Using `reverse()` to create the redirect url. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

> If you need to use something similar to the url template tag in your code

```py
from django.urls import reverse

def api_login(request):
    # Get post data
    post = json.loads(request.body)
    # Get username and password
    username = post.get('username', None)
    password = post.get('password', None)
    # Returned data object
    data = {
        "success": False,
        "username": username,
    }
    # Username and password
    if username == "" or password == "":
        data['success'] = False
        return JsonResponse(data)
    # Check if input is correct
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        data['success'] = True
        login(request, user)
        data['redirect'] = reverse('test-home') # import reverse from django.urls
        return JsonResponse(data) # return response with the redirect url
    else:
        data['success'] = False
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

In js redirect checking the response data

```js
if( 'redirect' in data) {
    window.location = data['redirect'];
}
```

You can add this either in

```js
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            // Success!
            console.log('Status: ' + request.status);
            if( 'redirect' in request.response) {
                window.location = data['redirect'];
            }
            onSuccess(request.response);
        }
```

OR

```js
    let onSuccess = function (data) {
        console.log('>> Success!');
        if( 'redirect' in data) {
            window.location = data.redirect;
        }
        console.log(data);
    }
```

Comment: Just tried and get a server error ````django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'app_test' is not a registered namespace````. As written I added ````app_name = 'app_test'```` in ````app_test.views.py````. Or do I have to import another script from ````app_test`````?

Comment: @michaelT providing the url name would be enough or you can add app_name in app.urls and try. You don't need to import from views

Comment: With Django 3.1.1 it seems that I do not need to use ````app_test```` in the ````reverse```` statement. This works: ````data['redirect'] = reverse('test-home')````. Thank you!